# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la info restante de un dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

espero se encuentren bien, actualmente tengo un problemita, es el siguiente:

tengo un dataframe con la info completa, llamemoslo df_limpio, este tiene las siguientes columnas:
NOMBRE, TIPO_DOCUMENTO, NUMERO_DOCUMENTO, DIRECCION, CORREO, INFO, BARRIO, ESTRATO, INFO1, INFO2, INFO3, telefono_1, telefono_2, telefono_3, celular_1, celular_2, celular_3.

y le estoy aplicando el siguiente código para quedarme con la info de aquellas personas que no tengan ni un solo número en las columnas  telefono_1, telefono_2, telefono_3, celular_1, celular_2, y celular_3.

```
df_limpio= pd.read_excel(self.rutalimpieza)
        vaciosTel1 = df_limpio[df_limpio['telefono_1'].isnull()]
        vaciosTel2 = vaciosTel1[vaciosTel1['telefono_2'].isnull()]
        vaciosTel3 = vaciosTel2[vaciosTel2['telefono_3'].isnull()]
        vacioscel1 = vaciosTel3[vaciosTel3['celular_1'].isnull()]
        vacioscel2 = vacioscel1[vacioscel1['celular_2'].isnull()]
        vacioscel3 = vacioscel2[vacioscel2['celular_3'].isnull()]
        vacioscel3.to_excel('Errores.xlsx', na_rep = "", index=False)
```

mi problema actual se basa en como puedo obtener la info de los restantes, es decir, de aquellos que si tenga al menos un solo número en cualquiera de las 6 columnas. Lo he intentado de la siguiente manera:

```
df_limpio[df_limpio.notnull()]
```

pero eso me devuelve prácticamente toda la información, ya que al menos existe data en cualquier columna(TODAS). Si lo aplico así enfocado solo en las columnas que necesito tampoco funcionaría.

```
columnas = ['telefono_1','telefono_2', 'telefono_3', 'celular_1', 'celular_2', 'celular_3']

for columna in columnas:
    limpieza =  columna
    df_limpio= pd.read_excel('self.rutalimpieza')
    vaciosDoc = df_limpio[df_limpio[limpieza].notnull()]
    vaciosDoc.to_excel('completos.xlsx', na_rep = "", index=False)
```

Podrían ayudarme para encontrar una solución?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo puedes hacer muy fácilmente utilizando la función [`pandas.DataFrame.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) (La función `isnull` que utilizas es un alias de `isna`) junto con [`pandas.DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) con el argumento `axis = 1` para revisar fila por fila.

Para no hacer todo el `datafram` que tienes hice uno genérico:

```
    Nombre  telefono_1  telefono_2  telefono_3  celular_1  celular_2  celular_3
0    Pedro         1.0         2.0         NaN        3.0        NaN        NaN
1     Juan         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
2   Arturo        10.0         NaN         NaN       20.0        NaN        NaN
3  Roberto         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Para obtener las filas donde todos los números telefónicos están vacíos puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
print(df.loc[df[['telefono_1', 'telefono_2', 'telefono_3', 'celular_1', 'celular_2', 'celular_3']].isnull().all(axis=1)])
```

Esto devuelve:

```
    Nombre  telefono_1  telefono_2  telefono_3  celular_1  celular_2  celular_3
1     Juan         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
3  Roberto         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Para obtener las filas donde alguno de los números telefónicos tenga datos puedes invertir la sentencia anterior utilizando `~`:

```
print(df.loc[~df[['telefono_1', 'telefono_2', 'telefono_3', 'celular_1', 'celular_2', 'celular_3']].isnull().all(axis=1)])
```

Esto devuelve:

```
   Nombre  telefono_1  telefono_2  telefono_3  celular_1  celular_2  celular_3
0   Pedro         1.0         2.0         NaN        3.0        NaN        NaN
2  Arturo        10.0         NaN         NaN       20.0        NaN        NaN
```

En lugar de imprimirlos los puedes asignar a nuevas variables y seguir procesando los nuevos `dataframes`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda @HeytalePazguato